# cuML UserWarning: Scoring failed. The score on this train-test partition for these parameters will be set to nan

Tags: python, typeerror, rapids, cuml, user-warning

i am trying to train a RF regression using `gridsearchcv`. I change all file types to float32 and i still get these warnings that i'm not sure how to solve.

my code:

```
combined_df=cpd.concat([train_df,evaluate_df])
combined_df = combined_df.astype({
    'Mcap_w': 'float32',
    'constant': 'int32', 
    'TotalAssets': 'float32',
    'NItoCommon_w': 'float32',
    'NIbefEIPrefDiv_w': 'float32',
    'PrefDiv_w': 'float32',
},error='raise')

print(combined_df.iloc[:,2:].info(),combined_df['Mcap_w'])

test_fold = [0] * len(train_df) + [1] * len(evaluate_df)

#p_test3 = {'n_estimators':[50,100,200,300,500],'max_depth':[3,4,5,6,7,8], 'max_features':[5,10,15,21]}
p_test3 = {'n_estimators':[20,50,200,500],'max_depth':[3,5,7,10], 'max_features':[25]}

tuning = GridSearchCV(estimator =cuRFr(n_streams=1, min_samples_split=2, min_samples_leaf=1, random_state=0), 
            param_grid = p_test3, scoring='r2', cv=PredefinedSplit(test_fold=test_fold))
tuning.fit(combined_df.iloc[:,2:],combined_df['Mcap_w'])
print(tuning.best_score_)
tuning.cv_results_, tuning.best_params_, tuning.best_score_
```

the print output:

```
 #   Column                        Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------                        --------------  -----
 0   TotalAssets                   896 non-null    float32
 1   NItoCommon_w                  896 non-null    float32
 2   NIbefEIPrefDiv_w              896 non-null    float32

dtypes: float32(3)
memory usage: 101.5 KB
None
```

for `print(combined_df['Mcap_w'])` this would return a series as `Name: Mcap_w, Length: 896, dtype: float32`

then i get 32 Warnings followed by 32 TypeErrors because i am using GridSearchCV.

> miniconda3/envs/rapid/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py:988: ***UserWarning***: Scoring failed. The score on this train-test partition for these parameters will be set to nan.

> TypeError: Implicit conversion to a host NumPy array via **array** is not allowed, To explicitly construct a GPU matrix, consider using .to_cupy()
> To explicitly construct a host matrix, consider using .to_numpy().

> miniconda3/envs/rapid/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py:988: ***UserWarning***: Scoring failed. The score on this train-test partition for these parameters will be set to nan.

> miniconda3/envs/rapid/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cudf/core/frame.py", line 402, in **array**
> raise TypeError( ***TypeError***: Implicit conversion to a host NumPy array via **array** is not allowed, To explicitly construct a GPU matrix, consider using .to_cupy()
> To explicitly construct a host matrix, consider using .to_numpy().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The errors mentioned already that we should

> ```
> consider using .to_cupy()
> To explicitly construct a host matrix, consider using .to_numpy().
> ```

however that's a little bit confusing. The function expects numpy array and as type `Float32`.

thus the fit method shuld look like this.

```
tuning.fit(train_df.iloc[:,2:].to_numpy(dtype='float32'),
                                  train_df['Mcap_w'].to_numpy(dtype='float32'))
```